# Is it possible to pause an R script that is running?

Tags: r

I am running a some analysis in R which is going to take at least 24 hours to finish. Is it possible to pause the function midway, so that I can take my computer to work and back?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 (I'm sorry should have mentioned that along with the question)

Comment: Tough. You could try suspend and resume, and hope for the best. Doesn't always pan out though...

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible AFAIK, but I believe you can just suspend your computer and the processes automatically will be paused.

If you are using Linux, you can also stop and continue a process manually using `killall -STOP R` and `killall -CONT R` commands. Take a look at [this article](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/11/23/how-to-pause-a-linux-process/) and the comment section there, which contain useful information regarding this.

On Windows, you can maybe use the Task Manager or install special software that is capable of doing that. But I really do not know as I do not use Windows on a regular basis.

EDIT: even if you use `kill` or `killall` to pause the process, but shutdown the computer, you will lose the data.

Comment: not with 'killall -STOP program', 'killall -CONT program' .. I should update the answer, I guess to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, please do. You could also mention 'Ctrl-z' and 'fg' / 'bg' which is job control from bash.  But we do not know the OS the OP is using.

Comment: Yes, I've done this with my Mac laptop (just by shutting the lid) and the script starts up again when I open it without any trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Linux, but I guess I'll try suspending the computer and see if that works.